# Why function in function in JS in not returning number?

Tags: javascript

I am building application in JS, and my function is not returning numbers (how I thought is supposed to)

```js
function function1(start, end) {
  var index = 0;
  return function() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (start < end) {
      if (index <= end) {
        return start + index;

      } else {
        return NaN;
      }
    } else {
      if (index <= start) {
        return end + index;
      } else {
        return NaN;
      }
    }

  };

}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var f = function1(2, 5);
  console.log(f);
}
```

instead of returning numbers, the outcome in console is:
[output in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trbC3.png)

Comment: `console.log(f())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a function. Therefore you need to call it like

`var f = function1(2, 5)()`

```js
function function1(start, end) {
  var index = 0;
  return function() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (start < end) {
      if (index <= end) {
        return start + index;

      } else {
        return NaN;
      }
    } else {
      if (index <= start) {
        return end + index;
      } else {
        return NaN;
      }
    }

  };

}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var f = function1(2, 5)();
  console.log(f);
}
```

This concept is called `Closure`. You can have a look at this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures